# How to validate a sender and send SMS other the OVH's API SMS?

Tags: api, sms, ovh

I try to send an SMS and there are two step (if I am not wrong) to reach this goal,

firstly, create and validate a sender for sending some message, here the link https://api.ovh.com/console/#/sms/{serviceName}/senders#POST. Sender is created but there is any sign to get his last code validation (SMS or mail) when validate this sender via the API, here the link

https://api.ovh.com/console/#/sms/{serviceName}/senders/{sender}/validate#POST.

Help please.

[image]

**Step to create sender:**
[image: Step to create sender]